# How best to create a simple, interactive, shareable plot with python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, data-visualization, bokeh

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. The python datavis landscape has now become huge and there are so many options that I'm a bit lost on what the best way to achieve this is.

I have an xarray dataset (but it could easily be a pandas dataframe or a list of numpy arrays).

I have 3 columns, A, B, and C. They contain 40 data points.

I want to plot a scatter plot of A vs B + scale*C where scale is determined from an interactive slider.

The more advanced version of this would have a dropdown where you can select a different set of 3 columns but I'll worry about that bit later.

The caveat on all of this is that I'd like it to be online and interactive for others to use.

There seem to be so many options:

- Jupyter (I don't use notebooks so I'm not that familiar with them but
  with mybinder I assume this is easy to do)
- Plotly
- Bokeh Server
- pyviz.org (this is the really interesting one but again, there'd seem
  to be so many options on how to accomplish this)

Any thoughts or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest both plotly.offline in JupyterLab and Plotly hosted in plotly servers.  The caveat of Plotly -online is your data is hosted in plotly servers. Also check this out: [dash-plotly](https://dash.plot.ly/)  All the above have worked well for me. I cant comment on the others.

Comment: From the description, it sounds like your largest expected number of data points is under 100, with three columns of values per datapoint? In that case there should be no need for mybinder, plotly online, or bokeh server; with data that small you can simply put a static HTML page on any web server that includes all of the combinations you want to make available.  You can use the pyviz.org tools to create such a page very easily, export it to HTML, and then post it online or send it by email.  Should be just a few lines of HoloViews or Panel+HoloViews code.

Comment: Thanks James. I think because my problem is so simple and all the tutorials cover much more complicated (and cooler) things that I'm struggling to find how to do this. I'm assuming just a HTML version can't do the maths of multiplying the data by the slider value? That means if I want more than a couple of preset slider values that I need a server-backed approach?

Comment: Ah, good point. If you only want a small number of discrete values, then you can still use a HoloViews HoloMap that will embed all of the combinations, but of course at some point that will become impractical, as it stores the full plot each time. If you want to select a fully continuous value, then the easy way to do that is indeed to have a Bokeh server backing it. But if that's an issue, I *think* you can still make it work if you write a tiny bit of JavaScript to do the scaling, using the process described at "Linking using custom JS code" https://panel.pyviz.org/user_guide/Links.html.

Comment: I personally prefer plotly. If your data is not that big you could consider to save every single plot as `html` file and then write a simple wrapper in html+css to switch between them. As advantages: you don't need a server and you can use a static website to share the plots, alternatively you can share them via email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are indeed many options and i'm not sure what is best but i use bokeh a lot and am happy about it. The example below can get you started. To launch this open a cmd in the directory where you save the script and run "bokeh serve script.py --show --allow-websocket-origin=*".

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider
from bokeh.models import Row,ColumnDataSource

#create the starting data
x=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
y_noise=[1,2,2.5,3,3.5,6,5,7,8]
slope=1 #set the starting value of the slope
intercept=0 #set the line to go through 0, you can change this later
y= [slope*i + intercept  for i in x]#create the y data via a list comprehension

# create a plot
fig=figure() #create a figure
source=ColumnDataSource(dict(x=x, y=y)) #the data destined for the figure
fig.circle(x,y_noise)#add some datapoints to the plot
fig.line('x','y',source=source,color='red')#add a line to the figure

#create a slider and update the graph source data when it changes
def updateSlope(attrname, old, new):
    print(str(new)+" is the new slider value")
    y = [float(new)*i + intercept  for i in x]
    source.data = dict(x=x, y=y)   
slider = Slider(title="slope", value=slope, start=0.0, end=2.0,step=0.1)
slider.on_change('value', updateSlope)

layout=Row(fig,slider)#put figure and slider next to eachother
curdoc().add_root(layout)#serve it via "bokeh serve slider.py --show --allow-websocket-origin=*"
```

The allow-websocket-origin=* is to allow other users to reach out to the server and see the graph. The http would be http://yourPCservername:5006/ (5006 is the default bokeh port). If you don't want to serve from your PC you can subscribe to a cloud service like Heroku: [example](https://ericstrong.org/running-a-bokeh-server-on-heroku-part-2/).

Comment: Thanks. That seems like a good option internally but I guess I need to then make that bokeh server publicly available somehow.